# Can MySQL ORDER BY FIELD get second parameter from inner joined table?

Tags: php, mysql

I got one table which's rows are item_id and tag_id. Every item_id is unique auto implement. item may have several tag_id.

I'm trying to get data sorted like this. When user visit page I catch item_id, go to table, get all tag_ids by item_id and try to return other item_ids which's have same tag_id.

Here is the problem when it returns items_id it is random, first i need to get items by first tag and then other.  Here is the SQL query.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT `item_id`, `rel`.`tag_id`
    FROM `itv_content_tags_rel` AS `rel`
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT `tag_id`
                 FROM `itv_content_tags_rel`
                 WHERE `item_id` = 65736 
                ) 
    AS kk ON kk.`tag_id` = `rel`.`tag_id`
    ORDER BY FIELD(`rel`.`tag_id`, 'rel.tag_id')
```

The ORDER BY FIELD row not working, [Her is table i got with whis query.][1]

When i change
`ORDER BY FIELD(`rel`.`tag_id`, 'rel.tag_id')`
By

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`rel`.`tag_id`, '3788') DESC
```

everything works perfectly [I got sorted table][2]

Is here any solution ?

Edit :

Here is the table i got after Tim's edit. 
[Tim's query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLfAA.png)
Is it possible to get sorted with item_id too like this.
[First sorted with tag_id then time_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEEPc.png)

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason adding `FIELD` appears to have fixed the problem is that it puts the `3788` ID first, followed by everything else, which coincidentally just happens to be one other ID.  If you want to sort on the `tag_id` column numerically, then you can just use `ORDER BY` and cast this column to something numeric:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, rel.tag_id
FROM itv_content_tags_rel AS rel
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT tag_id
    FROM itv_content_tags_rel
    WHERE item_id = 65736 
) AS kk
    ON kk.tag_id = rel.tag_id
ORDER BY CAST(rel.tag_id AS UNSIGNED)
```

Note that if you plan for the `tag_id` to only always contain numbers, maybe consider switching the type of this column to a numeric type so you can avoid casts like this in your queries.

**Update:** If you also want to sort using the `item_id` then just add another level to the `ORDER BY`, i.e. something like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(rel.tag_id AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(rel.item_id AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: I inserted this part in whole query and works well, thank you again, but i got problem, it orders by tag_id well but not with item_id, is it possible to short tag_id + item_ id,  i mean when tag_ids are same item_ids should be ASC or DESC.

Comment: Answer updated, just add another condition to the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Perfect, it was so easy, spend hours searching it, thanks again.